# How to map different url mappings in config.groovy when grails application integrated with Kerberos?

Tags: spring, grails, groovy

How to map different spring security url mappings in config.groovy when grails application integrated with kerberos?

The application will work only for below configuration in config.groovy
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = ['/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']]

But the requirement is to add different url mappings. How can we configure different url mappings??

Any help or alternative solution will be appreciated.

Thanks